# Ember.js - ENV.host setting being ignored - how can I diagnose this?

Tags: ember.js

I've got two very similar, and simple, apps.

I start both of them as 'ember s' with no other arguments.

They both rely on a backend found at http://localhost:8000 .

One of them works perfectly the other is convinced it should be making API calls to http://localhost:4200 .

So for instance rendering a list screen on the working one involves a GET to http://localhost:8000/api/todos . Rendering a list screen on the non-working one results in a GET request being made to http://localhost:4200/api/projects .

The location of the backend is defined in `config/application.js` via the `ENV.host` property.

How can I further diagnose this problem to see why the non-working app ignores `ENV.host` ?

Any ideas welcome.

Both the working and and non working apps are running on Ember 2.4.2

I'll put the relevant configs below in case that helps.

---

The problem `config/application.js` looks like this :

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    host: 'https://example.com',
    modulePrefix: 'spuv-ember',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    }
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
    // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
       ENV.host = 'http://localhost:8000';
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.baseURL = '/';
    ENV.locationType = 'none';

    // keep test console output quieter
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {

  }

  return ENV;
};
```

The working `config\application.js` looks like this :

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    host: 'https://example.com',
    modulePrefix: 'todo-ember',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    }
  };

  ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
    authenticationRoute: 'login',
    routeAfterAuthentication: 'todos',
    routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated: 'todos'
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
    ENV.host = 'http://localhost:8000';
    // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.baseURL = '/';
    ENV.locationType = 'none';

    // keep test console output quieter
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {

  }

  return ENV;
};
```

---

The non-working version of `app/adapters/application.js` showing the `ENV.host` value being used :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ENV from 'spuv-ember/config/environment';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  host: ENV.host,
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

---

The working version of `app/adapters/application.js` showing the `ENV.host` value being used (slightly different due to this app also using a form of authentication) :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ENV from 'todo-ember/config/environment';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
  host: ENV.host,
  namespace: 'api',
  authorizer: 'authorizer:drf-token-authorizer'
});
```

Comment: Are both projects using the same version of Ember? Are you setting the host in your application adapter?

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 : Thanks for your comment. Yes both are using the same version of Ember and yes I'm setting the host in the application adapter. I'll update the question showing the adapter setting in a few minutes. Will also dig out the actual ember version, which I can't recall off top of my head . Thanks again for your response.

Comment: Are you using authentication with just one or both?

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 Only one of the two apps has authentication and that's the one that works. It's my intention to add authentication to the working one but when I came across this problem I put off doing that.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 : I've done an edit to the question to show the host being set in the respective application adapters.

Comment: Just editted the question to include details of the Ember version under which the two apps are running.

Comment: There's a type in one of the comments above and for some reason I can't edit it so I'm just going to change it here : The original text was "Only one of the two apps has authentication and that's the one that works. It's my intention to add authentication to the working one but when I came across this problem I put off doing that." and it should have read "Only one of the two apps has authentication and that's the one that works. It's my intention to add authentication to the non-working one but when I came across this problem I put off doing that."

Comment: Do you have a separate adapter for `projects`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code looks correct to me and I've struggled with this myself. My only suggestion to you is to use the proxy option:

```
ember s --proxy http://localhost:8000
```

This will proxy all the requests through that domain and should hopefully allow you to continue development.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick although I find it a bit flaky that this is th only way of making it work ! Regardless, thanks for your help, I appreciate it.